# Sample iOS apps that consume RESTful web service

Tags: ios, web-services, rest

Does anyone know of any sample iOS apps that consume a RESTful web service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/restkit_ios-sdk/

Although this uses a third party library

Answer (score 0):

Use ASSIHTTPRequest framework.... its quite easy and reliable... you just need to create request object, set the verb and request data and send it... it works for both synchronous and asynchronous calls...

cheers

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest is discontinued.